# MotionEvent operation in android

Tags: android

I am working on `MotionEvent` by which i can get different - different gesture detection event.like this...

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            System.out.println("cancel event fire");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //System.out.println("Move event fire");
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            //System.out.println("ACTION_OUTSIDE event fire");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT:
            System.out.println("ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT event fire");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            System.out.println("ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT event fire");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
```

this gone good working but now i need  any `MotionEvent` method that detect as remove my fingermark from screen.so is there any event are there or if not then provide equevalent solution please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the removal of a finger from screen

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//do stuff
break;
```

The documentation would have told you this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html